# Why can't my Azure App service connect to my Azure Linux MongoDB instance?

Tags: linux, networking, azure

I have a standard Azure app service running NodeJS through IIS and a Linux VM running mongoDB.

When I set the firewall to allow all incoming connections into the VM, my app service has no trouble connecting to mongo. However, once I take this rule away, no connection is possible.

Now I know the solution seems obvious, "just add in a firewall rule", however, I don't know the IP address of the App Service as it's currently using shared hosting so I suspect it might change even if I did know.

There are currently 3 firewall rules.

- Name: AllowVnetInBound Port:Any Protocol:Any Source:VirtualNetwork Destination: VirtualNetwork
- Name: AllowAzureLoadBalancerInBound Port:Any Protocol:Any Source:AzureLoadBalancer Destination:Any
- Name:DenyAllInBound Port:Any Protocol:Any Source:Any Desination:Any

Any help would be appreciated as I'm pulling my hair out over this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Service supports dedicated outbound IP addresses for apps deployed using the App Service Environment (ASE) feature.  You can determine the outbound addresses by looking at the properties of your webapp.

For the foreseeable future, apps running in the public multi-tenant service will continue to use outbound addresses from a shared address pool.  Please upvote this [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/16790656-add-static-ip-address-for-outbound-traffic-without) if you would like to see dedicated outbound addresses.

[image: Azure Web App properties blade]